# OrientDB calculate PageRank

Tags: java, orientdb, pagerank

how can i calculate PageRank in OrientDB with Java API?
I import my graph into OrientDB as follow

```
    OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:./db/somegraph");
    OrientGraph graph = factory.getTx();
    GraphMLReader.inputGraph(graph, "./somegraph.graphml");
```

I am able execute any SQL Statements on it, get edges, nodes etc.

I have tried with Gremlin Script Engine such is described on https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-JUNG. But i get an error if try to import JUNG Module

Is there a better way to calculate PageRank on OrientDB? Or how should look an SQL Statement for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things are more simpler as it is.

1. Download Blueprints GraphJung jar file and Jung jar libs
2. Add it to lib of Orientdb
3. Implement it as it decribed at [Blueprint wiki](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/JUNG-Ouplementation)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately OrientDB don't have native PageRunk algorithm implementation, so you should use some 3rd party implementation like JUNG or implement it by your own.

I didn't use them so I can't advice an implementation.

What exactly issue do you have with using JUNG?

Comment: If i run for exsample gremlin from command line that in 'bin' folder of orientdb is. I get folowing error `gremlin> import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.scoring.PageRank  
Invalid import definition: import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.scoring.PageRank; reason: 
script1401906996899306423023.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.scoring.PageRank
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.scoring.PageRank` Same Error i get if try it esexute trouth Gremlin.command ... in java

Comment: Seems that _PageRank_ class is not in your class path. Check that you put all required jars in `orientdb/libs` and restarted the server.